# IzPack and accessibility (using a screen reader)

Tags: java, swing, accessibility, izpack

I'm curious if there is a way to set up an IzPack installer so that it works with screen readers (and has more accessibility features in general).  Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance,
-Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://packjacket.sourceforge.net/) out...it's kind of frontend GUI of IzPack... where you can specify and customize the installer screens as you want...

Comment: Thanks, I've played with PackJacket a bit.  It basically seems like a wizard for making installers.  Does it help with accessibility features?

Comment: Check this out, http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/accessibility2/

Comment: I know that Java includes an accessibility API.  What I'm getting at is: do I need to implement the accessibility features myself by modifying the IzPack source code, or is there an easier way to turn it on?

Comment: Yes, i think you will have to modify the code by yourself, but the good part is, most of the swing classes in IzPack already implements javax.accessibility.Accessible, so you won't have to create new classes to do that... check this out: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/codehaus/izpack/izpack-standalone-compiler/4.0.1/izpack-standalone-compiler-4.0.1-javadoc.jar!/com/izforge/izpack/installer/package-tree.html  , here JPanel, JLabel, JDialog etc already implements javax.accessibility.Accessible